# JSON Call to a possibly undefined method decode through a reference with static type Class

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to decode a json object from the deviantArt site the json object is like following

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "type": "photo",
  "title": "Cope",
  "url": "http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs50/f/2009/336/4/7/Cope_by_pachunka.jpg",
  "author_name": "pachunka",
  "author_url": "http://pachunka.deviantart.com",
  "provider_name": "deviantART",
  "provider_url": "http://www.deviantart.com",
  "thumbnail_url": "http://th03.deviantart.net/fs50/300W/f/2009/336/4/7/Cope_by_pachunka.jpg",
  "thumbnail_width": 300,
  "thumbnail_height": 450,
  "width": 448,
  "height": 672
}
```

and my code is like this

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import com.adobe.serialization.json.*;
var ldr = new URLLoader();
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onload);
ldr.load(ureq);
var ureq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://backend.deviantart.com/oembed?        url=http%3A%2F%2Ffav.me%2Fd2enxz7");
function onload(evt:Event):void
{
  var myData:Object = JSON.decode(ldr.data);
  trace(myData.title);
}
```

when i run it it gives an error
**Call to a possibly undefined method decode through a reference with static type Class**

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 and JSON : error 1061](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640683/as3-and-json-error-1061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decelerate the ureq, before you try to load it with the ldr ;)
And use the native top level JSON parser class

```
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    var ldr = new URLLoader();
    ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onload);
    var ureq: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://backend.deviantart.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffav.me%2Fd2enxz7");

    ldr.load(ureq);
    function onload(event: Event): void {

    var myData: Object = JSON.parse(event.target.data);
    for (var key: String in myData)
    trace(key + ":" + myData[key]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using Flash Pro CS 6.0, I have encountered the same problem in Flash CS 6.0, but never have in the older versions.

It seems that Adobe has integrated the code of project [`as3corelib`](https://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) into their Flash IDE. The `JSON` class you imported was overridden by the integrated one coming with Flash Pro CS6, which didn't have `decode` method, and therefore you got the error.

You can verify that by calling the decode method with full class reference:

```
var myData:Object = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(ldr.data);
```

And you should get an error like: `1000: Ambiguous reference to JSON`. That implies there are two copies of `com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON` loaded into the current compilation environment.

Answer (score -1):

With the help of 1st source code, use `parse()` instead of `decode` in `var myData:Object = JSON.decode(ldr.data);` statement. that will do better for execution.