# actionScript3 and JSON: can't figure how to adapt code to the keyframe

Tags: json, actionscript-3

SO, I'am new actionScript and JSON and can't figure out how to adapt the code to be able to paste it to the keyframe. I've got the code from.

http://snipplr.com/view/56283/

I get the Compiler error.

Scene 1, Layer 'AC', Frame 1, Line 2 1037: Packages cannot be nested

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;


    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        private var _jsonPath:String = "json_example.txt";

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage)
                init();
            else
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
            request.url = _jsonPath;
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
            loader.load(request);
        }


        private function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void 
        {
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
            var jsonArray:Array = JSON.decode(loader.data);

            trace("loader.data: " + loader.data);

            trace(jsonArray[0].Id);
            // 7

            trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].Id);
            // 5

            trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].StatusId);
            // 34

            trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].CreatedDateTime);
            // /Date(1310051914617+0100)/

            trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].Text);
            // Text

            trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].UserName);
            // Username

            trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].UserLocation);
            // UK

            trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].UserLanguage);
            // en-GB

            trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].IsCheckIn);
            // true

            trace(jsonArray[0].Tips[0].Id);
            // 5

            trace(jsonArray[0].Tips[0].FourSquareId);
            // 7e06c4b2-1fb5-4f35-9619-c99a384f5ae7

            trace(jsonArray[0].Tips[0].CreatedAt);
            // /Date(1310051914636+0100)/

            trace(jsonArray[0].Tips[0].Text);
            // Text

            trace(jsonArray[0].Tips[0].Username);
            // Username

            trace(jsonArray[0].Checkins);
            // 0

            trace(jsonArray[0].HereNow);
            // 0

            trace(jsonArray[0].TimeStamp);
            // /Date(1310051914639+0100)/

            trace(jsonArray[0].Venue.Id);
            // 7

            trace(jsonArray[0].Venue.FoursquareId);
            // cacbf3bd-f0aa-403d-9f9b-2056b4985ba1

            trace(jsonArray[0].Venue.Name);
            // Venue Name
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove all class specific things and use simply this:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;


var _jsonPath:String = "json_example.txt";
function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    request.url = _jsonPath;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
    loader.load(request);
}

init(); // call it so it can start


function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void 
{
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
    var jsonArray:Array = JSON.decode(loader.data);

    trace("loader.data: " + loader.data);

    trace(jsonArray[0].Id);
    // 7

    trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].Id);
    // 5

    trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].StatusId);
    // 34

    trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].CreatedDateTime);
    // /Date(1310051914617+0100)/

    trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].Text);
    // Text

    trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].UserName);
    // Username

    trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].UserLocation);
    // UK

    trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].UserLanguage);
    // en-GB

    trace(jsonArray[0].Mentions[0].IsCheckIn);
    // true

    trace(jsonArray[0].Tips[0].Id);
    // 5

    trace(jsonArray[0].Tips[0].FourSquareId);
    // 7e06c4b2-1fb5-4f35-9619-c99a384f5ae7

    trace(jsonArray[0].Tips[0].CreatedAt);
    // /Date(1310051914636+0100)/

    trace(jsonArray[0].Tips[0].Text);
    // Text

    trace(jsonArray[0].Tips[0].Username);
    // Username

    trace(jsonArray[0].Checkins);
    // 0

    trace(jsonArray[0].HereNow);
    // 0

    trace(jsonArray[0].TimeStamp);
    // /Date(1310051914639+0100)/

    trace(jsonArray[0].Venue.Id);
    // 7

    trace(jsonArray[0].Venue.FoursquareId);
    // cacbf3bd-f0aa-403d-9f9b-2056b4985ba1

    trace(jsonArray[0].Venue.Name);
    // Venue Name
}
```

Comment: Thanx, it helped! But I encounteres a new error.
I've deleted import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
And changed JSON.decode to JSON.parse.

code:




    'var jsonArray:Array = JSON.parse(loader.data);'




It deleted 3 new errors.
I Used [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640683/as3-and-json-error-1061]

new error:
**Scene 1, Layer 'AC', Frame 1, Line 26 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type Array.**

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Use it like: `var jsonArray:Object = JSON.decode(loader.data);`. Then trace/debug the data and cast it to Array later on. Or if you are sure it's array, then do `= JSON.decode(loader.data) as Array;`.

Comment: Well you really helped man. I figured out, that I didn't need to use the array. But for the record, it worked with parse instead of decode because of flashplayer 11.
Any ways, you got me to the goal. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You don't put code like this into keyframes, you put it into actionscript (.as) files.  Try saving your code as an *.as* file in the same folder as your .fla file. Then make 'Main' the document class in your Flash properties panel.

'Main' will have to extend 'MovieClip' not 'Sprite.'

It will also help if you remove the `'` from  `'package` in your code.

You may still get errors but they will be better ones and then we can think about them.